# Centering segments produced by the segment() function

Tags: r

Is there a way to specify a 'center' parameter using segments() without specifying individual x0/1 and y0/1 coordinates? Obviously align = 'center' does not work for this as the segments() function is base r code.

```r
#Here is short excerpt from my code:
plot.new()
height1 = 0.9
height3 = 0.7
height5 = 0.5
height4 = 0.3
height2 = 0.1 
segments(0, height1, species1_length/largestLength, height1, 
    lwd=3)
segments(0, height2, species2_length/largestLength, height2, 
    lwd=3)
segments(0, height3, species3_length/largestLength, height3, 
    lwd=3)
segments(0, height4, species4_length/largestLength, height4, 
    lwd=3)
segments(0, height5, species5_length/largestLength, height4, 
    lwd=3)
```

I ended up just doing it manually like so:

```r
segments(0.143, height1, ((species1_length / largestLength) * 2) + 0.143, 
         height1, lwd = 3)
segments(0.16, height2, ((species2_length / largestLength) * 2) + 0.16, 
         height2, lwd = 3)
segments(0.258, height3, ((species3_length / largestLength) * 2) + 0.258, 
         height3, lwd = 3)
segments(0.083, height4, ((species4_length / largestLength) / 1.2) +
           0.083, 
         height4, lwd = 3)
segments(0.155, height5, ((species5_length / largestLength) *
                            2) + 0.155, 
         height5, lwd = 3)
```

I just picked an amount to shift the x0 parameter (`segments(x0,y0,x1,y1)`) and corrected the `x1` value by that amount. The length of the line is still the same but my initial value and the proportional shift stay equidistant

Comment: You should write a new function that takes convenient inputs and translates them into the inputs that `segments()` wants.  Then use that instead of calling `segments()` directly.

Comment: If the previous comment is not enough of a hint, post some code that does what you want for one segment, and someone might show you how to simplify it to be more convenient when you want to draw lots of segments.

Comment: @user2554330 thanks I thought about writing a new function but I was hoping there was some aesthetic option I wasn't thinking of. I ended up just doing it manually like so:

Comment: `segments(0.143, height1, ((species1_length/largestLength)*2)+0.143, height1, lwd=3)
segments(0.16, height2, ((species2_length/largestLength)*2)+0.16, height2, lwd=3)
segments(0.258, height3, ((species3_length/largestLength)*2)+0.258, height3, lwd=3)
segments(0.083, height4, ((species4_length/largestLength)/1.2)+0.083, height4, lwd=3)
segments(0.155, height5, ((species5_length/largestLength)*2)+0.155, height5, lwd=3)`

Its not much but I'll explain it in case anyone else comes across this post

Comment: I just picked an amount to shift the x0 parameter (segments(x0,y0,x1,y1) corrected the x1 value by that amount. The length of the line is still the same but my initial value and the proportional shift stay equidistant

Comment: It's easier for others to see if you put that in your question.  I'll edit it in there; if you don't want that, you can revert my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a function to do this.  For example, I think this should work:

```
centered_segments <- function(length, height, largest = max(length), ...) {
  padding <- (largest - length)/2
  segments( padding, height, padding + length, height, ... )
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
centered_segments( species_lengths, heights, lwd = 3 )
```

where `species_lengths` is a vector containing all of the lengths and `heights` contains all of the heights, or one at a time like

```
centered_segments( species1_length, height1, largest_length, lwd = 3 )
```

etc.